# Triangle rasterization DirectX & Win32 Gdi

Tags: c++, c, directx, gdi

I'm currently following Andre Lamothe's book *Tricks of the Windows Game Programming Gurus* and trying to write my own software renderer with Win32 GDI. However, I got stuck at the triangle rasterization part of the book where the author is using Bresenham's line algorithm. I managed to get the rasterization to work on DirectX, but not on Win32 GDI despite identical rendering code. Both renders a triangle but the DirectX one renders it correctly while the Win32 almost renders it correctly

Link to my code: https://pastebin.com/VwySmQXS

It could be worth mention that the DirectX version is written in c++, while my own is written in C. I wasn't able to get a good screenshot of the two triangles so here is a picture painted in paint of how they both look.

Left is DirectX (how I want it to look), right is Win32 GDI:

[image]

Am I missing something here? Both `draw_triangle_2d` are called with the same arguments.

```
static void draw_top_tri(struct render_buffer *buffer,
                     int x1, int y1,
                     int x2, int y2,
                     int x3, int y3,
                     float r, float g, float b, float a)
{
unsigned int color = vec4_to_uint(vec4_mul(Vec4(r, g, b, a), 255.0f));
// this function draws a triangle that has a flat top

float dx_right,    // the dx/dy ratio of the right edge of line
    dx_left,     // the dx/dy ratio of the left edge of line
    xs, xe,       // the starting and ending points of the edges
    height;      // the height of the triangle

int temp_x,        // used during sorting as temps
    temp_y,
    right,         // used by clipping
    left;

// destination address of next scanline
unsigned int *dest_addr = NULL;

// test order of x1 and x2
if(x2 < x1)
{
    temp_x = x2;
    x2 = x1;
    x1 = temp_x;
} // end if swap

// compute delta's
height = (float)(y3 - y1);

dx_left = (x3 - x1) / height;
dx_right = (x3 - x2) / height;

// set starting points
xs = (float)x1;
xe = (float)x2 + (float)0.5;

// perform y clipping
if(y1 < MIN_CLIP_Y)
{
    // compute new xs and ys
    xs = xs + dx_left * (float)(-y1 + MIN_CLIP_Y);
    xe = xe + dx_right * (float)(-y1 + MIN_CLIP_Y);

    // reset y1
    y1 = MIN_CLIP_Y;

} // end if top is off screen

if(y3 > MAX_CLIP_X)
    y3 = MAX_CLIP_X;

// compute starting address in video memory
dest_addr = (unsigned int *)buffer->memory + y1 * buffer->width;

// test if x clipping is needed
if(x1 >= MIN_CLIP_X && x1 <= MAX_CLIP_X &&
   x2 >= MIN_CLIP_X && x2 <= MAX_CLIP_X &&
   x3 >= MIN_CLIP_X && x3 <= MAX_CLIP_X)
{
    // draw the triangle
    for(temp_y = y1; temp_y <= y3; temp_y++, dest_addr += buffer->width)
    {
        memset((unsigned int *)dest_addr + (unsigned int)xs,
               color, (unsigned int)(xe - xs + 1) * 4);

        // adjust starting point and ending point
        xs += dx_left;
        xe += dx_right;

    } // end for

} // end if no x clipping needed
else
{
    // clip x axis with slower version

    // draw the triangle
    for(temp_y = y1; temp_y <= y3; temp_y++, dest_addr += buffer->width)
    {
        // do x clip
        left = (int)xs;
        right = (int)xe;

        // adjust starting point and ending point
        xs += dx_left;
        xe += dx_right;

        // clip line
        if(left < MIN_CLIP_X)
        {
            left = MIN_CLIP_X;

            if(right < MIN_CLIP_X)
                continue;
        }

        if(right > MAX_CLIP_X)
        {
            right = MAX_CLIP_X;

            if(left > MAX_CLIP_X)
                continue;
        }

        memset((unsigned int *)dest_addr + (unsigned int)left,
               color, (unsigned int)(right - left + 1) * 4);

    } // end for

} // end else x clipping needed

} // end Draw_Top_Tri

static void
draw_bottom_tri(struct render_buffer *buffer,
            int x1, int y1,
            int x2, int y2,
            int x3, int y3,
            float r, float g, float b, float a)

{
unsigned int color = vec4_to_uint(vec4_mul(Vec4(r, g, b, a), 255.0f));
// this function draws a triangle that has a flat bottom

float dx_right,    // the dx/dy ratio of the right edge of line
    dx_left,     // the dx/dy ratio of the left edge of line
    xs, xe,       // the starting and ending points of the edges
    height;      // the height of the triangle

int temp_x,        // used during sorting as temps
    temp_y,
    right,         // used by clipping
    left;

// destination address of next scanline
unsigned int *dest_addr;

// test order of x1 and x2
if(x3 < x2)
{
    temp_x = x2;
    x2 = x3;
    x3 = temp_x;
} // end if swap

 // compute delta's
height = (float)(y3 - y1);

dx_left = (x2 - x1) / height;
dx_right = (x3 - x1) / height;

// set starting points
xs = (float)x1;
xe = (float)x1; // +(float)0.5;

// perform y clipping
if(y1 < MIN_CLIP_Y)
{
    // compute new xs and ys
    xs = xs + dx_left * (float)(-y1 + MIN_CLIP_Y);
    xe = xe + dx_right * (float)(-y1 + MIN_CLIP_Y);

    // reset y1
    y1 = MIN_CLIP_Y;

} // end if top is off screen

if(y3 > MAX_CLIP_X)
    y3 = MAX_CLIP_X;

// compute starting address in video memory
dest_addr = (unsigned int *)buffer->memory + y1 * buffer->width;

// test if x clipping is needed
if(x1 >= MIN_CLIP_X && x1 <= MAX_CLIP_X &&
   x2 >= MIN_CLIP_X && x2 <= MAX_CLIP_X &&
   x3 >= MIN_CLIP_X && x3 <= MAX_CLIP_X)
{
    // draw the triangle
    for(temp_y = y1; temp_y <= y3; temp_y++, dest_addr += buffer->width)
    {
        memset((unsigned int *)dest_addr + (unsigned int)xs,
               color, (unsigned int)(xe - xs + 1) * 4);

        // adjust starting point and ending point
        xs += dx_left;
        xe += dx_right;

    } // end for

} // end if no x clipping needed
else
{
    // clip x axis with slower version

    // draw the triangle

    for(temp_y = y1; temp_y <= y3; temp_y++, dest_addr += buffer->width)
    {
        // do x clip
        left = (int)xs;
        right = (int)xe;

        // adjust starting point and ending point
        xs += dx_left;
        xe += dx_right;

        // clip line
        if(left < MIN_CLIP_X)
        {
            left = MIN_CLIP_X;

            if(right < MIN_CLIP_X)
                continue;
        }

        if(right > MAX_CLIP_X)
        {
            right = MAX_CLIP_X;

            if(left > MAX_CLIP_X)
                continue;
        }

        memset((unsigned int *)dest_addr + (unsigned int)left,
               color, (unsigned int)(right - left + 1) * 4);

    } // end for

} // end else x clipping needed

} // end Draw_Bottom_Tri}

ENGINE_CORE_EXPORT void
draw_triangle_2d(struct render_buffer *buffer,
             int x1, int y1,
             int x2, int y2,
             int x3, int y3,
             float r, float g, float b, float a)
{
// this function draws a triangle on the destination buffer
// it decomposes all triangles into a pair of flat top, flat bottom

int temp_x, // used for sorting
    temp_y,
    new_x;

// test for h lines and v lines
if((x1 == x2 && x2 == x3) || (y1 == y2 && y2 == y3))
    return;

// sort p1,p2,p3 in ascending y order
if(y2 < y1)
{
    temp_x = x2;
    temp_y = y2;
    x2 = x1;
    y2 = y1;
    x1 = temp_x;
    y1 = temp_y;
} // end if

// now we know that p1 and p2 are in order
if(y3 < y1)
{
    temp_x = x3;
    temp_y = y3;
    x3 = x1;
    y3 = y1;
    x1 = temp_x;
    y1 = temp_y;
} // end if

// finally test y3 against y2
if(y3 < y2)
{
    temp_x = x3;
    temp_y = y3;
    x3 = x2;
    y3 = y2;
    x2 = temp_x;
    y2 = temp_y;

} // end if

// do trivial rejection tests for clipping
if(y3 < MIN_CLIP_Y || y1 > MAX_CLIP_X ||
   (x1 < MIN_CLIP_X && x2 < MIN_CLIP_X && x3 < MIN_CLIP_X) ||
   (x1 > MAX_CLIP_X && x2 > MAX_CLIP_X && x3 > MAX_CLIP_X))
    return;

// test if top of triangle is flat
if(y1 == y2)
{
    draw_top_tri(buffer, x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, r, g, b, a);
} // end if
else
    if(y2 == y3)
    {
        draw_bottom_tri(buffer, x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, r, g, b, a);
    } // end if bottom is flat
    else
    {
        // general triangle that's needs to be broken up along long edge
        new_x = x1 + (int)(0.5 + (float)(y2 - y1) * (float)(x3 - x1) / (float)(y3 - y1));

        // draw each sub-triangle
        draw_bottom_tri(buffer, x1, y1, new_x, y2, x2, y2, r, g, b, a);
        draw_top_tri(buffer, x2, y2, new_x, y2, x3, y3, r, g, b, a);

    } // end else

} // end Draw_Triangle_2D
```

Comment: Firewalls are blocking my access to your link. Can you paste your code, as text, into your post?

Comment: Just a question, is your program set to be DPI aware? Pretty sure DirectX does that automatically while GDI does not. (I am blind so can't see your sample images, just was something I thought of).

Comment: The code you currently show seems independent from the rendering technology (gdi vs dx). So the problem doesn't lie here but in how you use those technologies. Should should show that too.